# Json Parsing with Array containing Struct of Struct using Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

my json: (stored in minijson.json)

```
{
  "arr": [
    {
      "st1": {},
      "st2": {
        "a": {}
      },
      "val": 0.0,
      "x": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

i am using spark version 2.1.0 to read json.

read code:

```
minidf = spark.read.json("minijson.json")
minidf.printSchema()
```

output:

```
root
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- val: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

I do not understand why it is not able to detect `st1`, `st2` and `a` fields which are present in json.

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not creates the Column if the key has empty key as `"abc": {}` It must have at-least a key and value to create a column.

Below is a simple example by adding a key and value

```
{
"arr": [
  {
    "st1": {
    "name": ""
  },
    "st2": {
      "a": {
        "abc": ""
      }
    },
    "val": 0.0,
    "x": "1"}
  ]
}
```

Wich will have a schema as

```
root
 |-- st1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- st2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: double (nullable = true)
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: yes. I knew this. even I tried replacing empty key with empty array viz. `"abc":{}` to `"abc":[]` and it works. but the problem is i need to have solution  with existing json which I had posted in question.

Comment: you can always set the schema yourself.

Comment: thanks @Assaf but here the problem with predefined schema is, the object `st1` and `a` can have any level of nesting and we have no control over sender's schema.

Comment: @desaiankitb You can try to use an external tool to extract the json schema and then  convert it to spark schema manually